# Is there a way to use constants inside Spring Data @Query annotation value?

Tags: java, spring, jpql, spring-data

I don't want to hardcode constant values, I would rather specify them through a reference variable.

For example, rather then writing the next query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT u FROM UserModel u WHERE u.status = 1")
```

..I would like to extract the hardcoded value '1' and write something like:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT u FROM UserModel u WHERE u.status = UserModel.STATUS_ACTIVE")  //doesn't compile
```

Is there a way to specify constants like in the second example inside spring-data queries?

Answer (score 49):

You have to use fully qualified class name like this:

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM UserModel u WHERE u.status = com.example.package.UserModel.STATUS_ACTIVE")
```

<s>The bad thing about it though is that an IDE would not recognise this as an usage of the class UserModel. The only advantage is that you can keep the value in one place, which is sufficient most of the time.</s> This has been resolved in [IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/03/spring-data-improvements-in-intellij-idea-2017-1/). I don't know about other IDEs.

Comment: this raises an exception that 'com not defined' .. At least for my

Comment: Did you apply the fully qualified package name for your purpose? I mean you have to point to the correct, existing class with its fully qualified name.

Comment: Yes I did. I solved the problem in passing in the enum values to compare against. not elegant, but working

Comment: It works for me, with fully qualified name, but the field that is being compared is defined as `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` in the entity.

Answer (score 14):

I would recommend creating an `Enum` and a field of that enum on the entity.

```
public enum UserModelStatus{
     ACTIVE, INACTIVE
}

public UserModel{

    /* Other fields ommitted */

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserModelStatus status;

    /* Get/Set Method */
}
```

Then create your repository method:

```
@Repository
public interface UserModelRepository extends JpaRepository<UserModel, Long>{

    public List<UserModel> findByStatus(UserModelStatus status);

}
```

Using Spring Data you won't even need to write JPQL just call the method like:

```
   @Autowired
   UserModelRepository userModelRepository;

   public void someMethod(){
       List<UserModel> userModels = userModelRepository.findByStatus(UserModelStatus.ACTIVE);
   }
```

Comment: How can I easily negate the findByStatus(UserModelStatus status)? I mean get all userModel where UserModelStatus is **not** status?

Comment: findByStatusNot(UserModelStatus status)

Comment: This shows the full power of spring data. Stick to it for simple queries, no need to write sql yourself.

Answer (score 11):

Use as follows:

In the repository interface, define a constant as follows:

```
public static final String USER_QUERY = "SELECT u FROM UserModel u WHERE u.status = " + UserModel.STATUS_ACTIVE;
```

Now you can use

```
@Query(value=USER_QUERY)
```

Answer (score 11):

I've managed to use class String constant in query via SpEL T() operator, which gives you access to static methods and constants on a given class. For String I have to wrap expression with single quotes ('), probably it will be needed for you as well (if QuerySyntaxException occurs).

Try something like this,

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM #{#entityName} u " +
       "WHERE u.status = #{T(fully.qualified.path.UserModel).STATUS_ACTIVE}")
```

Note: somehow it doesn't work if you use UserModel instead of #{#entityName}.

In docs its mentioned briefly, see: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-beandef-xml-based

Don't know since when this is supported, I've got spring-data-jpa 1.4.3, spring-framework 3.2.17

Comment: If you want to use parameterized statements with a native query, you can do a `SELECT columns FROM table_name WHERE column_name = ?#{T(fully.qualified.path.ClassName).STATIC_CONSTANT_VARIABLE}` (adding `?`: `?#{T(...`). I needed `WHERE column_name NOT IN (?#{T(namespace.ClassName).STRING_COLLECTION_VARIABLE})` and without the `?` it wasn't parameterized so didn't behave as expected.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this seems to be 'No' for a standard solution.

Some JPA implementations may have solutions of their own but hibernate for one does not seem to and does not seem to support any of the methods suggested by other answers here.

Answer (score -2):

When you want to use constants directly inside your @Query annotation you can write something like:

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM UserModel u WHERE u.status = " + UserModel.STATUS_ACTIVE)
```

Comment: This would return an error saying that the attribute value must be constant.

Comment: That's what I said. This answer is about using constants in the @Query annotation.

Comment: Yes but CONSTANT + CONSTANT is not constant any more :) Hence the error.

Comment: This works for me. If you are expecting a string, don't forget to wrap it in single quotes `'` in the query.

Comment: `The value for annotation attribute Query.value must be a constant expression`