# QuerySyntaxException with enum

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, h2

I have a UserAssignmentRole class like this :

```
@Data
@Entity
public class UserAssignmentRole {
    ...
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public Role role;
}
```

And the Role is enum, it looks like this:

```
public enum Role{
    admin,
    member,
    pending
}
```

Now when in my repository I try to query to select all with role of admin, it gives me error:

```
@Query("select uar from UserAssignmentRole uar where uar.role=Role.admin")
public List<UserAssignmentRole> listAdmin(Long userID, Long assignmentID);
```

How this can be solved?

Error : **org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'Role.admin'**

Full error : https://pastebin.com/tk9r3wDg

Comment: Did you use the fully qualified class to you enum? with package. Or you maybe find an  answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402988/is-there-a-way-to-use-constants-inside-spring-data-query-annotation-value

Comment: Where did you placed enum? Can you try to move enum definition to UserAssignmentRole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try not to write this sql by yourself but with repository create code like this:

```java
@Repository
public interface UserAssignmentRolelRepository extends JpaRepository<UserModel, Long>{

    public List<UserAssignmentRole> findByRole(Role role);

}
```

And then:

```java
@Autowired
UserAssignmentRolelRepository repository ;

public void someMethod(){
   List<UserAssignmentRole> userAssignmentRoles = repository.findByRole(Role.admin);
}
```

#### UPDATE 1

As it was point out [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59544356/11733759): non-conventional naming. You can change labels in your enum to uppercase.

```java
public enum Role{
    Admin,
    Member,
    Pending
}
```

and then:

```java
@Query("select uar from UserAssignmentRole uar where uar.role=com.example.package.Role.Admin")
public List<UserAssignmentRole> listAdmin(Long userID, Long assignmentID);
```

#### UPDATE 2

But if you really want to have lowercase in DB.
It requires more code to change. Enum change to:

```java
public enum Role{
    Admin("admin"),
    Member("member"),
    Pending("pending");

    private String name;

    Role(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public static Role parse(String id) {
        Role role = null; // Default
        for (Role item : Role.values()) {
            if (item.name.equals(id)) {
                role = item;
                break;
            }
        }
        return role;
    }
}
```

In `UserAssignmentRole`

```java
//    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Convert(converter = RoleConverter.class)
    private Role role;
```

And additional class:

```java
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class RoleConverter implements AttributeConverter<Role, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Role role) {
        return role.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public Role convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return Role.parse(dbData);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is a strange but intended behaviour of Hibernate since 5.2.x
An enum value is a constant and you're using a non-conventional naming (lowercase)

Take a look at [this issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12429) and Vlad Mihalcea's long explanation of the [performance penalty](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-performance-penalty-of-class-forname-when-parsing-jpql-and-criteria-queries/).

> If you’re using non-conventional Java constants, then you’ll have to set the hibernate.query.conventional_java_constants configuration property to false. This way, Hibernate will fall back to the previous behavior, treating any expression as a possible candidate for a Java constant.