# Hibernate QuerySyntaxException with enum when hibernate.query.conventional_java_constants is set to false

Tags: java, hibernate, enums

Background: Java/Wildfly/Hibernate application with Java 8 and Hibernate 5.3.9.Final.

I have a named query like this

```
  @NamedQuery(
    name = DailyStatement.GET_EXPORT_DATES_BY_ORGASTRUCTUREIDS_FOR_MISEXPORT,
    query =
            " SELECT d.orgaStructureId, MIN(d.workingDay), MAX(d.workingDay) "
                    + "   FROM DailyStatement d "
                    + "  WHERE d.orgaStructureId in (:orgaStructureIds) "
                    + "    AND d.misExportFlag = false "
                    + "    AND d.state = net.shop.ob.ptm.types.timerecord.EDailyStatmentsState.CLOSED "
                    + "    AND d.workingDay <= :maxWorkingDay "
                    + " GROUP BY d.orgaStructureId "
```

When starting the application I get an error

> DailyStatement.getExportDatesByOrgaStructureIdsForMISExport failed
> because of: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
> Invalid path:
> 'net.shop.ob.ptm.types.timerecord.EDailyStatmentsState.CLOSED' [
> SELECT d.orgaStructureId, MIN(d.workingDay), MAX(d.workingDay)    FROM
> net.shop.ob.ptm.dm.entities.DailyStatement d   WHERE d.orgaStructureId
> in (:orgaStructureIds)     AND d.misExportFlag = false     AND d.state
> = net.shop.ob.ptm.types.timerecord.EDailyStatmentsState.CLOSED     AND d.workingDay <= :maxWorkingDay  GROUP BY d.orgaStructureId ]

The referenced, allegedly erroneous enum looks like this

```
public enum EDailyStatmentsState {
    OPEN(0),
    ERROR(1),
    CLOSED(2);

    private int id;

    //(...)
```

The error does not occur if I set the hibernate parameter

```
hibernate.query.conventional_java_constants
```

to false

in persistence.xml. In blog post https://vladmihalcea.com/the-performance-penalty-of-class-forname-when-parsing-jpql-and-criteria-queries/ the meaning of this parameter is explained. I would understand the error, if the constant EDailyStatmentsState.CLOSED would not follow standard Java naming conventions, but as far as I can see, it does.

Because of performance reasons I would like to set the Hibernate option

```
hibernate.query.conventional_java_constants
```

to false and fix the root cause of the error. What could be causing this?

BTW, This question is not a duplicate of e.g. this question [QuerySyntaxException with enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59543649/querysyntaxexception-with-enum)
as the non-standard lower-case enum naming is causing the error there, unlike in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem is that the validation of the classname in Hibrnate is done with the following regex in class org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper:

```
[a-z\d]+\.([A-Z]{1}[a-z\d]+)+\$?([A-Z]{1}[a-z\d]+)*\.[A-Z_\$]+
```

This causes classes with two successive uppercase letters not to validate. This is [a known Hibernate bug (HHH-14059)](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14059) which has been internally [fixed](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/3431/commits) in Hibernate by replacing the offending regex with

```
[a-z\d]+\.([A-Z]+[a-z\d]+)+\$?([A-Z]{1}[a-z\d]+)*\.[A-Z_\$]+
```

I fixed the issue with a workaround by renaming the class to contain no consecutive uppercase letters.

The issue has also been fixed in Hibernate 5.4.19.